# Extract data from multiple tables using SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to make a list of all the principal investigators (`facility_investigators` table in the given AACT database) of studies whose `official_title` (in the `studies` table) include the keyword 'fibrillation'. I also want the information on the sponsors of all such studies (sponsors table in AACT).

I have tried the following code so far -

```sql
SELECT * FROM studies
WHERE official_title ILIKE '%fibrillation%'
```

Above code gives me all the studies with the word fibrillation in their title.

```sql
SELECT * FROM sponsors
WHERE agency_class ILIKE '%NIH%'
```

This code will give me a full list of  studies where the sponsor is only NIH (studies on the fibrillation plus thousands of others)

Similarly,

`SELECT * FROM facility_investigators`  gives me a full list of investigators for all the studies (studies on fibrillation plus thousands of others)

Each study is identified by a unique id which is there in all the tables.

I want to ask how do I combine these 3 commands to get a **condensed list of only fibrillation studies with NIH as sponsor along with list of their respective investigators?**

[image: studies]

[image: facility_investigator]

[image: Sponsors]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results (preferably as *text tables* int he question).

Comment: Hello, I have added the required sample data, I cam making a table for sample output

Comment: . . What does `id` refer to?  Is it the same thing in all three tables?

Comment: yes, 'id' is the same thing in all the 3 tables, it is the common link between all the 3 tables

Comment: Sorry. I see some of these ids might not be unique.  It's better to provide the complete create table statement with constraints, if available.

Comment: Each table should have a unique not null key (primary key).  Any references to other tables should usually be "to" the primary key of the referenced table.  Can you add that detail to the question?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your time. I have added a unique ID to all the tables which are unique for each value and a mct_ID that has common values, which is how I want to link the data. Example mct_ID 21 meets my criteria for a study having the word fibrillation, having the agency_class NIH

Comment: Let me know if i need clarify about what I am asking here..

Comment: @BR27 Having at least answered the basic question, it's possible you might consider reviewing slight changes to the structure (re: normalization).  For a relatively small amount of data, the `'%pattern%'` approach might be ok.  You may be able to extract lists of unique values, making the joins much more efficient, while reducing some duplication of data.  There's also 'full text' searches, where we can't avoid data embedded within less structured text.  Just thoughts to consider. If you don't really control the structure, there's not too much you can do, unless moving the data is possible.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tips! I will keep them in mind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a join between the 3 tables, along with some filtering to restrict the result to specific name patterns in `agency_class` and `official_title`:

```
SELECT sp.*, st.*, fi.*
  FROM sponsors AS sp
  JOIN studies  AS st
    ON sp.mct_id = st.mct_id
  JOIN facility_investigators AS fi
    ON fi.mct_id = st.mct_id
 WHERE agency_class   ILIKE '%NIH%'
   AND official_title ILIKE '%fibrillation%'
;
```

Reduce the select list as needed.